# How to resize multiple labels to automatically fit inside of a UIView When Orientation Changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel, autolayout

I have been trying to get this to work for days now and I'm sure its due to my lack of understanding of how `AutoLayout` really works.

I have a `UIView` centred in a `ViewController`. Then I have 9 `UILabels` inside that `UIView`. I am creating a countdown app and each `UILabel` will hold either the months, days, hours, minutes, or seconds remaining. I want to make it so that when the phone is rotated into landscape mode the `UILabels` auto resize and make the font bigger since there is more space in `landscape` mode than in `portrait`.

The issue I keep running into is if I set the `UILabel` frame to the size of the text in `portrait` mode then it doesn't resize when the phone is rotated. But if I make the `UILabel` frame large enough to hold the font when the phone is rotated, then the text does in fact auto resize. However, my issue with this is that I can't get everything lined up in `portrait` mode if I have to use `landscape` sized frames.

Any help on how I should be approaching this or the best way to do it would be very much appreciated.

Oh I should also add that I don't want to use a single label to display all the time because I am going to have labels underneath the time value that says what unit that time is representing (hours, days, minutes, etc) and I won't be able to get those labels underneath lined up with the correct value unless I use separate `UILabels` for each unit of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be setting any frames, if you're using auto layout. Give your labels constraints to the left and right edges of the UIView, and give that UIView constraints to the left and right edges of its superview. When you rotate, everything should expand to fill  up the larger space. Set the font in IB to the large size you want in landscape (make sure your label is tall enough for that size), and change the "auto shrink" menu from "fixed font size" to "minimum font size", and that should handle the font change automatically.

Comment: Is there a way I can evenly spread out all the time labels within the subview?

Comment: @Dmitry, yes, one way to do that is to add spacer views between each of your labels, and between the top and bottom of the view and the closest label. These spacer views can just be UILabels with no text in them. You need to hook all the labels from top to the bottom with vertical constraints, and set all the spacer labels to have the same (but not fixed) height.

Comment: Ok I'm trying all this out right now. One other thing I still don't understand is if I have a subview that holds the time labels and I have 5 time labels inside that subview, do I not have to set constraints between each of the labels? 

For the UILabels inside the subview, only two of them touch the edge. The far left one touches the left edge and the far right one touches the right edge. If i set constraints for them only then when I rotate only those labels stay in place.

Comment: @Dmitry, I don't know what your label setup looks like, so i can't really comment on that. Vertically, all the labels (including the spacers) need to have constraints to one another, but horizontally, I can't say without knowing more about your setup.

Comment: Here is what my setup currently looks like

http://postimg.org/image/kt3qtewzn/

I also was trying to add colons (:) in between each label but it was making it even more difficult to keep it all lined up. I have the constraints you mentioned and this is what it does now

http://s29.postimg.org/snil3epvn/Screen_Shot_2014_05_02_at_3_15_12_PM.png
http://s29.postimg.org/ga5qwi077/Screen_Shot_2014_05_02_at_3_15_21_PM.png